# Тире или дефис? И является ли слово "принадлежности" приложением?

Tags: определения, дефис-тире

> Облигации, размещаемые эмитентом за пределами страны - принадлежности эмитента, называются международными облигациями.

Верно ли поставлено тире? Или нужен дефис? И чем является "принадлежности" - приложением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, допустимо вместо "страна, на территории которой действует эмитент" сказать "страна принадлежности эмитента", но никаких тире и дефисов!

Мой вариант (немного отредактированный с учетом критики @Ксения):

**Облигации, размещаемые эмитентом за пределами страны его принадлежности, называются международными облигациями.**

Comment: Интересно, как это страна может принадлежать эмитенту. Эмите́нт  — организация, которая выпускает (эмитирует) ценные бумаги для развития и финансирования своей деятельности.

Comment: @Ксения  Термин "страна принадлежности" употребляется для обозначения принадлежности субъекта стране, а не страны субъекту.

Comment: @Ксения Из Нацкорпуса:  Принятый в июне закон позволяет оказывать помощь всем судам, вне зависимости от страны принадлежности, а также чаще применять оружие. [Ксения Нака. Японские моряки вышли на смену коллегам в район Африканского Рога // РИА Новости, 2009.07.06]

Comment: Страна принадлежности эмитента - это нормально (три слова в Р.п.).?

Comment: @Ксения Придираетесь? В научнообразном учебном пособии еще и не такое бывает.  А у нас тут, похоже, что-то в таком духе.

Comment: Просто интересно. Там ведь стояло тире, а с тире получается стандартная грамматическая конструкция, но  в ней только одно плохо: страна принадлежит эмитенту. Как-то все "подозрительно".

Comment: @Ксения Тире порождает бессмыслицу. Впрочем, я только о тире писал, а целиком все предложение не давал. Дополню ответ с учетом Вашего замечания о Р.п.